# WSO2 audience not matched

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm having a problem with OAuth2 and WSO2 IS as KM.
When the server generates a jwt token, I get the error `None of the audience values matched the tokenEndpoint Alias` since, in the said token, the audience is preceded by a "\t".

In the service provider configuration the "Enable Audience Restriction" is checked and the uri are correct, however, when the token is generated a "\t" gets appended at the beginning of the audience field. I'm using jwt.io as a decoder.

What could it be causing the issue? I've already tried to switch the token Issuer in identity.xml

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: In which version of the WSO2 IS as KM you see this?

Comment: the version is 5.7.0 GA @JayangaKaushalya

Comment: @JayangaKaushalya do you have any update? thank you

Comment: Can be a bug in 5.7.0 GA. If possible can you try the 5.8.0GA version? Which is the latest.

Comment: @JayangaKaushalya unfortunately I cannot try with the 5.8 GA since my system is in a production environment and I have no access to the development environment. Is there any issue on github with a similar problem? many thanks.